# Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS and save the new image

Tags: html, css, image

Is there anyway that I can convert the image to Gray scale or such other types by adding filters in (html and css) and then Save the new image back into server.

This is what I have and I want to be able to keep the grayscale page stationary and save it as a new photo
I also have svg file

```
<title>canvas image manipulation</title>
<style>
    img {
filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);

    }

    img:hover {
        filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox */
        filter: gray; /* IE */
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="profile.jpg">
<input type="button" class="img:hover" value="button">
```

Comment: I would make a PHP script to do add filters and return the new image, then I would execute the script via the JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I just updated my quesiton with my file

Comment: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 </filter>
</svg>

Answer (score 3):

This link might help you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

As far as re-saving it on the server, I don't think you'll need to do that as long as the HTML filters the image.

Comment: I need to let the user apply the filter and then save the new image

Comment: Ahh okay, I had a feeling you were going to say that haha. This link may possibly help you as well, there are quite a few tutorials on there for the canvas function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am gono read that, and see if I can take any hint ... Hopefully I can get more hints here